# How to add to std::variants?

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

So I have:

```
typedef std::variant<int,float,std::string> VarType;
```

And I want to be able to do:

```
VarType a = 1;
VarType b = 1;
VarType c = a + b;
```

When the types are mixed, it's cool for it to throw.

Answer (score 4):

```
VarType c = std::get<int>(a) + std::get<int>(b);
```

More general:

```
VarType c = std::visit([](auto x, auto y) -> VarType 
                       { 
                           if constexpr(!std::is_same_v<decltype(x), decltype(y)>)
                           {
                               throw;
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               return x + y; 
                           }
                       }, a, b);
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/b1YOaU1ohSbN3wtH)

Comment: Your more general approach (which is the one I want, I don't know the types before hand), doesn't compile.

Comment: ```#include <variant>
#include <string>

typedef std::variant<int,float,std::string> VarType;

int main()
{
    VarType a = 1;
    VarType b = 2;

    VarType c = std::visit([](auto&& a, auto&& b) ->VarType { return a + b; }, a, b);
}
```